# How to split a string by amount of characters in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, split, batch-processing

I have about 6GB of various text files, the files have many lines but each record is missing its commas so all the data is in 1 record.  I want to create a batch file where I can add commas at the appropriate places in each "record". I'm hoping to add commas so I can then import this into a database.

For example the file would be structured like this.

```
IDnameADDRESSphoneEMAILetc
IDnameADDRESSphoneEMAILetc
IDnameADDRESSphoneEMAILetc
```

Each field has a unique length which I know, and it's static between all files.
For example

```
ID - 10 characters
NAME - 40 characters
ADDRESS - 30 characters
etc
```

This will need to be run on an ongoing basis as new files come in so I'm hoping for something I can give a non technical person they can just run.
Any quick way to do this in a bat file?

Comment: You can do this with the `SET` command.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `SET /?` to read the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your provided example, here is a quick powershell command, *(despite no tag)*:

```ps1
(GC 'Report.txt' | Select -First 1).Insert(10,',').Insert(51,',').Insert(82,',') > 'Fixed.txt'
```

It takes the first line of `Report.txt`…

1. After `10` characters insert `,`
   *(0 + 10 = 10) + 1*
2. After another `40` characters insert `,`
   *(11 + 40 = 51) + 1*
3. After another `30` characters insert `,`
   *(52 + 30 = 82) + 1*
4. etc.

…then outputs the line complete with insertions to `Fixed.txt`

Just continue the `.Insert(<number>,',')` sequence for your other fixed width column sizes and ensure you've changed the filenames to suit your circumstances.

**Edit**

The following as an update to your comment and subsequent edit should work for all lines in the file.

```ps1
GC 'Report.txt' | % {($_).Insert(10,',').Insert(51,',').Insert(82,',')} | Out-File 'Fixed.txt'
```

Comment: This seems to work great but only did line 1 of the file.  How can I have it go through every line?

Comment: Mr Lahey, your question was specific, `"various text files, each with a single record of data"`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't word it properly then.  Each line has 1 long record, but each file has many records.  Its like a CSV with all commas removed.  I will edit my post.

Comment: Mr Lahey, I have edited my answer to incorporate your reworked parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Using your example above. Note we count the characters starting from 0, then tell the set to use letters starting at a certain count, counting the word length from there. See bottom for layout.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (filename.txt) do (
  set str=%%a
  set id=!str:~0,2!
  set na=!str:~2,4!
  set add=!str:~6,7!
  set ph=!str:~13,5!
  set em=!str:~18,5!
  set etc=!str:~23,3!

echo !id!,!na!,!add!,!ph!,!em!,!etc!
)
```

Characters assigned in a string as:

```
I D n a m e A D D R E  S  S  p  h  o  n  e  E  M  A  I  L  e  t  c
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

ID starts at Character 0 and is 2 characters, including itself `:~0,2`

name starts at character 2 and is 4 characters long `:~2,4`

etc..

For many files just add another loop as a main loop or give a list of files.

Comment: Sorry I had to update my post.  I had incorrectly stated each file has 1 record, when I meant each file has many records that have no commas.

Comment: @MrLahey Then xoncept stays the same. We just read from file then.